# How to achieve Default Select values in Multi-select prompt in jasper server?

Tags: jasperserver

Could you please help me, How to achieve Default Select values in Multi-select prompt in jasper server? for example, suppose that I have access to (India, usa, London) & other have access to India only. My requirement is multi select filter should select by default base on user value.

Comment: What do you mean by `default base on user value`? Can you pass it as parameter to your report from your client.

Comment: It seems it would mean "a default based on a user-dependent value". E.g. if user Raj opens the report, by default "India" would be pre-selected in the Input Control; if user John opens the report, the pre-selected value would be "London".